# ActiveMQ Artemis client on Java 1.6

Tags: java-6, activemq-artemis

I am trying to find a workable recipe to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis from Java 1.6.

Any ideas? Any way to leverage another client and protocol to connect to Artemis?

Comment: Did my answer address your comment? If so please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not please elaborate as to what is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a legacy HornetQ client that supported JDK 1.6. Artemis has worked to maintain backwards compatibility with HornetQ so it should work OK.

Also, you could use a STOMP client that supports JDK 1.6. STOMP is a very simple protocol so even if you couldn't find one with JDK 1.6 support you could write your own if necessary.